# Exceptions for Microsoft Outlook 2010 Auto-Reply function

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, auto-reply

There are some scripts which are sending emails to me. Now I want to setup an auto-reply, but the stated sender of the automated scripts should not get an auto-reply message. Can I define a rule for specific addresses, which should never get an auto reply message even when auto reply is set up?